# PowerShell get specific member of the Cmdlet output

Tags: powershell

How can I retrieve a specific member's value from a cmdlet's output in PowerShell?

For example, I am using [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostAddresses("google.com") to get the IP address of a domain. The output contains some additional values as well and I want to extract only the value of the field "IPAddressToString".

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostAddresses("google.com")

Address           : 3456489900
AddressFamily     : InterNetwork
ScopeId           :
IsIPv6Multicast   : False
IsIPv6LinkLocal   : False
IsIPv6SiteLocal   : False
IPAddressToString : 172.217.5.206
```

I piped the output of the above command to Get-Member as shown below:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostAddresses("google.com") | Get-Member -Name IPAddressToString


   TypeName: System.Net.IPAddress

Name              MemberType     Definition
----              ----------     ----------
IPAddressToString ScriptProperty System.Object IPAddressToString {get=$this.Tostring();}
```

It only displays the Property but not its value.

Does PowerShell provide a method to extract these values from the command output?

Thanks.

Comment: the `Get-Member` cmdlet DOES NOT show values, it shows name, type, & structural info. [*grin*] if you want to see the values, use `Select-Object` or -better - `[System.Net.DNS]::GetHostAddresses("google.com").IPAddressToString[1]`. on my system, the `[0]` address is ipv6, the `[1]` address is ipv4.

Comment: Thanks. I also found an alternate method. [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostAddresses("google.com") | Select -ExpandProperty "IPAddressToString" will return the IP address as well.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - As that is, in fact, a correct way to do it, and is in general the recommended way, propose it as an answer. For completeness, you can also include the information that the querent posted in a reply comment.

Comment: @NeonFlash - you are most welcome! [*grin*] the `| Select` solution works ... but seems a tad indirect _to me_. use what fits how you think about it!

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - done - and thank you for the reminder! [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason `Get-Member` didn't give you want you want is that it shows name/type/structure info, but not *values*. [*grin*] if you want to see the values of the properties of an item, use `$Item | Select-Object -Property *` to show all the props and their values.

to get the value you want for use in a script, use dot-notation to get the value ... like this ...

```
@([System.Net.DNS]::GetHostAddresses("google.com")).IPAddressToString[1]
```

that will give you the value of the 2nd item in the array of IP addresses returned by the call. on my system, that is the IPv4 address - the `[0]` item is an IPv6 address.

as you found, another way to get that same info is to pipe to the `Select-Object` cmdlet like this ...

```
([System.Net.DNS]::GetHostAddresses("google.com") |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'IPAddressToString')[1]
```

if you want to be certain to get the address type that you desire, use something like this ...

```
@([System.Net.DNS]::GetHostAddresses("google.com")).
    Where({$_.AddressFamily -eq 'Internetwork'}).
    IPAddressToString
```

that gets the addresses from the target, filters for the IPv4 address, and then gives the value